# Drop down nav won't render all options on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On this website: https://videogamestore.best, my nav menu will not display all the game platforms on mobile.

However, when I minimize my desktop window, to say, 300px, the nav menu displays all the options like it's supposed to.

This leaves me unsure of what to do.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="/"><img id="navbar-logo" src="{{ asset('storage/images/gamer_logo2.png') }}" alt="Gamer logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div style="z-index: 99" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('playstation') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('playstation') }}">{{ ('Playstation') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('xbox') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('xbox') }}">{{ ('Xbox') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('nintendo') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('nintendo') }}">{{ ('Nintendo') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('pc') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('pc') }}">{{ ('PC') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('login') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="{{ Request::is('register') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="{{ route('cart') }}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            @if(Cart::count() > 0 && Cart::count() < 10)
                                <div class="cart-count-bg"><span style="margin-left: 0.51rem;"><b>{{ Cart::count() }}</b></span></div>
                            @elseif(Cart::count() > 9)
                                <div class="cart-count-bg"><span style="margin-left: 0.2rem;"><b>{{ Cart::count() }}</b></span></div>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('playstation') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('playstation') }}">{{ ('Playstation') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('xbox') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('xbox') }}">{{ ('Xbox') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('nintendo') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('nintendo') }}">{{ ('Nintendo') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="{{ Request::is('pc') ? 'page-item active' : '' }} nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('pc') }}">{{ ('PC') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>

                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('cart') }}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    @if(Cart::count() > 0 && Cart::count() < 10)
                                        <div class="cart-count-bg"><span style="margin-left: 0.51rem;"><b>{{ Cart::count() }}</b></span></div>
                                    @elseif(Cart::count() > 9)
                                        <div class="cart-count-bg"><span style="margin-left: 0.2rem;"><b>{{ Cart::count() }}</b></span></div>
                                    @endif  
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

In short, my nav bar isn't responsive despite what my minimized browser window suggests.

Can anyone help me identify the solution here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using `align-items: center;` on the `nav` element, which seems to center the whole navigation, expanding it upwards and outside of the viewport.

If I am right, it doesn't serve any purpose (you are already centering the logo and navigation elements by centering the content inside the `div.container` element).

So if `align-items: center;` on `nav` is not needed - remove it and your navigation should be visible.

Comment: Can you reference the line where ```align-items: center;``` exists? It's not on the nav element and I can't find it in the code I posted here. I've also commented out this in my app.css and no change occured: ```.navbar-collapse {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          /* align-items: center; */
} ```

Comment: The code you posted in your question is not really helpful to reproduce the problem. For future reference (when your website is changed) it would be great if you reproduce this problem in a basic form in your question, to help others having a similar problem.

That aside, I inspected the link you added to your question and in `app.css` on line 6154 you are adding `align-items: center;` to your `.navbar` class. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I don't quite know how I would reproduce this problem in a basic form though. Nonetheless, the fix works. So, thanks!